# setup root folder in vs code in a python project

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

I have a project called **hello**, and path to this project is /home/Ubuntu/work/greetings/hello.
my virtual environment named **hello** is created in /home/ubuntu/work/virtaul_environments/hello.

My project structure is something like below:

```
|-greetings
    |-hello
        |-hello_to_family
            |-say.py
        |-hello_to_friend
            |-say.py
        |-utils
            |-utils.py
```

in above structure every say.py contains import from greetings folder.

```
from greetings.hello.utils.utils import good_morning
```

Now the problem is my interpreter does not recognize greetings folder, it says

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'greetings'
```

My settings.json file contains:

```
{
    "python.pythonPath":"/home/ubuntu/work/virtual_environments/hello/bin/python"
}
```

Sorry if it is a naive question, I have just shifted to vs code from pycharm so I am getting bit of trouble with vs code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to append the module’s path to `PYTHONPATH`:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/Ubuntu/work/"
```

Comment: where should I put this line, in settings.json or some where else to set it up permanently?

Comment: @AwaishKumar You just need to run it in your terminal window from VS

Comment: it works in terminal but I wanted to add it permanently so I added it in .env file, thanks